# Why Javascript is not working under appending?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table in my html and I used append to attach all rows in the table using jquery. Part of the append section is shown below. I have an input section to change numbers but now this input click is not working anymore.

I wonder why? If I move the code back to my html table, it works.
Also, the delete button is not working as well. I suspect this is to do with append feature?

```
$('.bundle-main').append('<li class="td td-amount">\
       <div class="amount-wrapper ">\
          <div class="item-amount ">\
             <div class="sl">\
               <input class="min am-btn" name="" type="button" value="-" />\
               <input class="text_box" name="" type="text" value="3" style="width:30px;" />\
               <input class="add am-btn" name="" type="button" value="+" />\
              </div>\
              </div>\
              </div>\
              </li>');
```

PS: The reason I want to use append is because I want to dynamically control my content and my css is working fine.

Do you know why?

Comment: Are you adding an event handler to your input buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're appending the inputs dynamically, you need to make sure that the click listeners are added **after** the append. Otherwise they will not be present in the DOM and the click listener will not be attached.

Just attach your listeners after the append call.

Comment: I wrote my all my listeners in a js file and attached it after the append div in my html page, like this <script type="text/javascript" src="__FRONT__/js/jquery.js"></script> but it is still not working. Do I have you attach all my listeners and the appending in one file? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Because your event handler is defined before input is appended.
You have 2 choices:

**No1.** After append input, then defined the event handler.

**No2.** Just use .on('click') on the wrapper like following:

```
$('.bundle-main').on('click', '.add.am-btn', function(){
  // To Do
});
```

Comment: I wrote my all my listeners in a js file and attached it after the append div in my html page, like this <script type="text/javascript" src="__FRONT__/js/jquery.js"></script> but it is still not working. Do I have you attach all my listeners and the appending in one file? Thanks

Comment: Thanks Ray. You are a bit later than Pabs.